# What is the maximum processor frequency that Linux could run on?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling

Theoretically, if an extremely fast computer could be built (100s of GHz or even terahertz), what is the maximum frequency that could be expressed in the variable used by the scheduler allocate cycles?
For simplicity let's assume one instruction per cycle and no memory or io bottlenecks.

Comment: what will the version number of linux be in the year 2318?

Comment: nice question. RAM is Know